# Custom Layout Manager in Draw2d

Tags: eclipse-plugin, draw2d

All,

Can we define a custom Layout Manager in draw2d ? If yes, can anyone please explain the steps for the same? I need to come up with a TableLayout where I can dynamically add rows and columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about how to do it with Draw2D itself but have a look at [this snippet](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.gef/test/org.eclipse.zest.tests/src/org/eclipse/zest/tests/swt/CustomLayout.java?view=markup&root=Tools_Project) on how to do it with [Zest](http://eclipse.org/gef/zest/) (which is based on Draw2D). Also note there is a [new version coming up](https://github.com/irbull/org.eclipse.zest_2_0) with a refactored layout library.